# Testing application on iPad device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to get the statistical details( memory details, object allocations etc.) , when my app is running on the actual device. Not in the simulator. Is there a way to attach the instruments or some other tool to device? ( When i build and debug on the device from xcode).

Is it true that memory details that shown in the simulator is very different from running in the actual device? I need to know the correct way to how to test in the actual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able to run the performance tools on the device. In Xcode make sure you have selected the 'Device' configuration and the go to Run->Run With Performance Tool->